# Vue.js 2- is it a bad practice to break down form into smaller components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a big form with around twenty fields, to achieve minimum code amount, I created independent components for inputs and selects, then an array of fields is passed into `v-for` to create the form.

But soon enough I found it very complicated to handle form serialization and linked selects (say one select for the list of states, and another select for cities depending on the selected state).

If I write the form in one component, however, there'll be a lot of repeated divs, classes, etc.

So which way is a better?

Comment: Better way is one that fits better in your case :) If you have a lot of logic, it's better to break it into component for easier testing in debugging.

Comment: Nothing speaks against small form components. Especially when you can reuse them multiple times in one form. If possible you always want to program a function/part/module only once.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading and referring to the official doc and codes of bootstrap-vue, I'm now pretty convinced that independent and reusable components are necessary.

To solve my problem of form serialization and linked selects, official doc [Form Input Components using Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events) would help.